# How to create a json with R and controll quotes

Tags: r, json, replace, jsonlite

I want to create data in R and then export as json. For this I create a list and transform it with jsonlite:: toJSON.
In the json I get all characters in quotes. How can I remove specific quotes.
as.name() and noquote() does not work with jsonlite:: toJason.
Is there a solution to get this done.

Here an example:

```
x = list(test="false")

x_j=jsonlite::toJSON( x,pretty = T,  auto_unbox = T)
{
  "test": "false"
}
```

However, the export should look like this:

```
{
  "test": false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`jsonlite::toJSON`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/jsonlite/versions/1.5/topics/toJSON%2C%20fromJSON) will only convert an R [logical](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/logical.html) vector to a [json boolean](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/boolean.html).

In your case, that means you need `FALSE`, rather than `"false"`, which is an R [character vector](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/character.html) and gets converted to a [json string](https://restfulapi.net/json-data-types/).

```r
x = list(test=FALSE)

jsonlite::toJSON(x, pretty = T,  auto_unbox = T)

# {
#   "test": false
# }
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Ok I never tried the easiest solution